# Mass Update And Mass Edit From List View clashes with State/Country Picklists

Tags: appexchange, list-view, country-and-state

The following appears when I click on “Mass Update” in a list of recently created leads:

> core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesHandledException: Object type not accessible. Please check permissions and make sure the object is not in development mode:
>
> `((CreatedDate = TODAY)) ) ORDER BY StateCode ASC LIMIT 10000` ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:159 No such column `StateCode` on entity `Lead`.
>
> If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
>
> Original queryString was: `SELECT Id, Company, Email, LeadSource, Name, Salutation, FirstName, LastName FROM Lead WHERE ( ((IsConverted = FALSE)) AND ((CreatedDate = TODAY)) ) ORDER BY StateCode ASC LIMIT 10000`

I tried with leads created before we turned on State/Country Picklists and Mass Update works fine.

The email contact in [the AppExchange page for the package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ) lists an email (cchen@salesforce.com) that no longer exists within the company.

Short of disabling the Mass Update package, which would be a bummer, any idea on how to deal with this?

Comment: I tried reinstalling. No luck.

Comment: Cross posted in Salesforce Answers [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZqRSQA0).

Comment: Answer from Salesforce Answers: "It seems that the code running behind does not have accessible check of StateCode field thats why this error is coming. And you can't update the package code."

Comment: that package was written long before state and country codes feature came out. However -- you can most definitely edit the code as it is not a managed package